# java JFrame getLocationOnScreen returns wrong result? @ Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, jframe, ubuntu-12.04

I need to get JFrame location to save application position. But the problem is getLocationOnScreen() returns incorrect result. Or at least it seems so.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setLocation(100, 100);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            Point point = frame.getLocationOnScreen();
            System.out.println(point);
        }
    });
}
```

In my opinion the code above must yield (100, 100), but instead it prints "java.awt.Point[x=101,y=128]".

How can I get the correct (100, 100) result?

UPD: Also sometimes I get (100, 100) or (101, 128). And I really can't understand the logic of it.

UPD: Two different runs of this code.
[image]

Comment: setLocation moves to the x,y based on the parent, getLocationOnScreen will get location based on screen... But... I do see 100,100 in after running your code here. Which java version are you using?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode) Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the same java version but in windows. Seems that JFrame is not parentless in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, 1 and 28 somehow look like x window system frame dimensions.

Comment: It is likely that that getLocation is being delegated to the content pane, which is taking into account the extra space taken up by the frames border

Comment: Then it seems to be something buggy since 1 and 28 are the upper border of your frame and it may take as the frame where it starts.

Comment: OK, thank you very much, I have solved the problem. It was because of old compiz version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setLocation moves to the x,y based on the parent, getLocationOnScreen will get location based on screen...

There is no guarantee that getLocation and getLocationOnScreen would be the same.. getLocation is "relative" while getLocationOnScreen is absolute.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation(int, int)

This is my output for your code:

```
java.awt.Point[x=100,y=100]
```

Which java version are you using? Mine is 1.7.0_25, maybe there is a difference between default behaviors for JFrame since the top component "should" have as parent the screen.

```
Update from comments:
java version "1.7.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode) Ubuntu 12.04
```

Sometimes you get 100,100 and sometimes 101, 128

Different behaviors for JFrame.setLocation JFrame.getLocationOnScreen
In windows I always get 100, 100 for this particular case.